# Cast date to varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to cast this to have a varchar result..

```
select date_trunc('week', '2013-02-01'::date);
```

I'll be using this to a "Where" clause that has a varchar datatype

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `to_char` in order to be able to control the format of the varchar result:

```
select to_char(date_trunc('week', '2013-02-01'::date), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you just cast it to TEXT?

```
select date_trunc('week', '2013-02-01'::date)::text;
```

Comment: As long as you don't need a certain format (and you are asking for none), this is simpler than `to_char()`.